# How do I return the users to the state, they were before impersonation?

Tags: c++, service, impersonation

I want to use impersonation in my project to run it in Services correctly.

I see some code that do something like this:

Get `explorer.exe` PID, then `OpenProcess` with that PID and `DuplicateTokenEx`

after that, the code `CreateThread` and then `SetThreadToken` and `ResumeThread`

This is the code:

```
HANDLE ExplorerToken(VOID) 
{
    PROCESSENTRY32W procEntry;
    HANDLE  Snap = NULL; 
    HANDLE  Process = NULL;
    HANDLE  PToken = NULL;
    LPCWSTR TProce = L"explorer.exe";
    DWORD   TargetSID = -1;
    DWORD   SId = -1;
    DWORD   TargetPID = -1;
    BOOL    WellDone = TRUE;
    HANDLE ExplorerToken = NULL;
        if(ExplorerToken != NULL)
    {
        return ExplorerToken;
    }

    SId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
    procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32W);
    Snap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (!Process32FirstW(Snap, &procEntry))
    {
        WellDone = FALSE;
    }
    do
    {
        if (lstrcmpiW(procEntry.szExeFile, TProce) == 0)
        {
            if (ProcessIdToSessionId(procEntry.th32ProcessID, &TargetSID) && TargetSID == SId)
            {
                TargetPID = procEntry.th32ProcessID;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (Process32NextW(Snap, &procEntry));


    if(TargetPID == -1)
    {
        WellDone = FALSE;
    }
    Process = OpenProcess(MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, FALSE, TargetPID);

    if(!OpenProcessToken(Process, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, &PToken))
    {
        WellDone = FALSE;
    }

    if(!DuplicateTokenEx(PToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, NULL, SecurityImpersonation, TokenImpersonation, &ExplorerToken))
    {
        WellDone = FALSE;
    }

    if(WellDone == FALSE)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        return ExplorerToken;
    }
}

VOID CcCryptUnprotectData(LPVOID data)
{
    PCUD_PARAMS pCudParams;
    pCudParams = (PCUD_PARAMS)data;

    pCudParams->bRetVal = pCudParams->fp_CryptUnprotectData(
        pCudParams->pDataIn,
        pCudParams->ppszDataDescr,
        pCudParams->pOptionalEntropy,
        pCudParams->pvReserved,
        pCudParams->pPromptStruct,
        pCudParams->dwFlags,
        pCudParams->pDataOut);

}

BOOL _CryptUnprotectData(__in  DATA_BLOB *pDataIn, __out_opt  LPWSTR *ppszDataDescr, __in_opt   DATA_BLOB *pOptionalEntropy,
    __in  PVOID pvReserved, __in_opt   CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT *pPromptStruct, __in DWORD dwFlags, __out DATA_BLOB *pDataOut )
{
    HANDLE ThreadHandle;
    CUD_PARAMS cudParams;
    DWORD   ThreadIdArray   = 0;
    HMODULE hmCrypt32 = NULL;
    HANDLE ExplorerToken;

    cudParams.pDataIn = pDataIn;
    cudParams.ppszDataDescr = ppszDataDescr;
    cudParams.pOptionalEntropy = pOptionalEntropy;
    cudParams.pvReserved = pvReserved;
    cudParams.pPromptStruct = pPromptStruct;
    cudParams.dwFlags = dwFlags;
    cudParams.pDataOut = pDataOut;

    cudParams.bRetVal = FALSE;

    if(MyCryptUnprotectData_OutlookPassword == NULL)
    {
        if(hmCrypt32 == NULL)
        {
            hmCrypt32 = LoadLibraryW(L"Crypt32.dll");
        }
        MyCryptUnprotectData_OutlookPassword = (BOOL (WINAPI* )(DATA_BLOB *pDataIn, LPWSTR *ppszDataDescr, DATA_BLOB *pOptionalEntropy, PVOID pvReserved, CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT *pPromptStruct,  DWORD dwFlags, DATA_BLOB *pDataOut))GetProcAddress(hmCrypt32, "CryptUnprotectData");
    }

    cudParams.fp_CryptUnprotectData = MyCryptUnprotectData_OutlookPassword;

    ExplorerToken = ExplorerToken();

    if(ExplorerToken == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    ThreadHandle =  CreateThread(NULL,
        0,                                                   // use default stack size  
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)CcCryptUnprotectData,       // thread function name
        (LPVOID)&cudParams,                                  // argument to thread function 
        CREATE_SUSPENDED,               
        &ThreadIdArray); 

    if(ThreadHandle == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if(!SetThreadToken(&ThreadHandle, ExplorerToken))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    ResumeThread(ThreadHandle);

    WaitForSingleObject(ThreadHandle, INFINITE);

    return cudParams.bRetVal;
}
```

I use this code and do my work, now **I want to return the users to the state, they were before impersonation**

I know I should keep the handle before `SetThreadToken` and then after I've done my work, again `SetThreadToken` with the kept token.

Now I want you to help me to do that.

Comment: Wouldn't you just clear the thread token, via `SetThreadToken(&ThreadHandle, 0)`?

Comment: `SetThreadToken(&ThreadHandle, 0)` will be useful if `ThreadHandle` was a token equal to the token before impersonation, it means I should take a backup from  `ThreadHandle` but I don't know how????

Comment: `ThreadHandle` is a thread handle, not a token. If you clear thread's token it goes back to using the original process token, which is usually what you want.

Comment: I would be wary of doing this from outside the thread. Any handles it has opened will remain valid and retain the impersonated access. To fix that you need to close and reopen, which requires active co-operation from the thread.

Comment: I'm beginner in it and its incomprehensible for me, the teacher told me I should get a back up from token `backup = GetThreadToken` then `SetThreadToken(&ThreadHandle, ExplorerToken)` and after that again `SetThreadToken backup`  **I don't know how to get backup**   :(

Comment: he said if I don't backup from `ThreadHandle` the `SetThreadToken(&ThreadHandle, 0)` doesn't be able to returns the users to the state, they were before impersonation!!!

Comment: That might be true in the context of a service (although I don't think so, bit I haven't done it for a long time).

Comment: `GetThreadToken` has the slight disadvantage that it doesn't seem to exist. `OpenThreadToken` might just work. But unless the thread was already impersonating, which seems unlikely, setting the thread token to zero seems simplest.

Comment: @biprinea your teacher clearly does not understand how impersonation actually works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Get explorer.exe PID, then OpenProcess with that PID and DuplicateTokenEx

That is a VERY OLD (Win9x) approach to getting a session's user token. Since you are already using the WTS API, use `WTSQueryUserToken()` instead, passing it the session ID that you want to impersonate.

> after that, the code CreateThread and then SetThreadToken and ResumeThread.

Another option is to pass the user token to the thread in the `lpParameter` of `CreateThread()`, and then the thread can call [`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612.aspx) after it starts running.

> I use this code and do my work, now I want to return the users to the state, they were before impersonation

If a thread needs to stop impersonating before it terminates, it should call [`RevertToSelf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379317.aspx).  If the impersonation should last until the thread terminates, there is no need to stop impersonating manually.

> I know I should keep the handle before SetThreadToken and then after I've done my work, again SetThreadToken with the kept token.

That is useful if the thread is *already* impersonating one user and then needs to stop impersonating, or to impersonate a different user, and then later needs to impersonate the first user again.  But you are not doing that in your example.

Now, with that said, your `_CryptUnprotectData()` function is leaking the thread object, as it is not calling `CloseHandle()` after `WaitForSingleObject()` is done.  But more importantly, it is wasted overhead to create a new thread and then make the calling thread block until the new thread is terminated.  The calling thread may as well just do the work directly.  In your example, `_CryptUnprotectData()` can omit `CreateThread()` altogether and just call `fp_CryptUnprotectData()` directly, wrapped with calls to  `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()`/`RevertToSelf()`.  You do not need to create a new thread just to use impersonation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you said _`That is useful if the thread is already impersonating one user and then needs to stop impersonating`_  It's what I want to do!  I want to impersonate user, do something then stop impersonating ->  I should keep the handle before `SetThreadToken `and then after I've done my work, again `SetThreadToken` with the kept token |  I don't know how to do this?

Comment: @biprinea You took that line of my answer out of context, you ignored the second half of the sentence. If you just want to stop impersonating PERIOD then just call `RevertToSelf()` and move on. You don't need the previous token unless you need to re-impersonate it AGAIN after stopping impersonation. Even then, you could just reuse the original token you started with, you don't need to ask the thread for it unless you are in a situation where you CANT remember the token (which is not the case in your example).

Comment: @biprinea a thread does not start impersonating, so there is no previous impersonation token to restore until YOU start the impersonation. YOU control the tokens YOU use to impersonate with. `SetThreadToke()` assigns/removes an impersonation token only. You are so focused on `SetThreadToken()` that you are not paying attention to the bigger picture, or the other things I explained in my answer

Comment: If I use `RevertToSelf()` How do I understand that impersonation stops? I think I should use it here:    
  
 ResumeThread(ThreadHandle); 
 WaitForSingleObject(ThreadHandle, INFINITE);
 RevertToSelf();
 CloseHandle(ThreadHandle);
 return cudParams.bRetVal;

Comment: @biprinea `RevertToSelf()` stops impersonation for the *calling thread*, so you CANT call it after `WaitForSingleObject()`. The worker thread that you create with `CreateThread()`, the thread that is actually impersonating, will have to call `RevertToSelf()` before terminating. Which is redundant in your example since the thread can simply terminate without stopping impersonation, it does not need to revert.

Comment: I want to do this: [ink](http://uploads.im/PYtMG.png)    You say I Shoul this: [link](http://uploads.im/zP6B3.png)   is it true?

Comment: In this class the teacher doesn't allow us to use these functions, we should use the functions I told in my question, and revert the impersonation  **What should I do?    How do I understand that impersonation reverts?  :((**

Comment: Get rid of the worker thread, it is useless overhead. Other than that, I only changed ExplorerToken() to WTSQueryUserToken(), and SetThreadToken() to ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()/RevertToSelf(). If you must use the original functions, so be it, it doesn't change what else I said. Pass a NULL thread handle to SetThreadToken() to set/revert impersonation for the calling thread. To revert, pass a NULL token to SetThreadToken() if the calling thread was not previously impersonating. If it was, you are responsible for keeping track of the tokens you use so you can re-set them as needed.

Comment: If you absolutely must query a thread's current impersonation token before changing it, if for no other reason than your code does not know if the thread is already impersonating (if it does not know, you are not managing your thread correctly), then you will have to use OpenThreadToken().

Comment: is it true if I write something like this:   HANDLE h;   HANDLE h2;  h=CreateThread(...);   h2=h1;  ?

Comment: @biprinea is what true?

Comment: **the problem is solve, but I want to know is it true if I define 2 variables:**   HANDLE h; HANDLE h2;   **and then say one variable is equal to CreateThread**   h=CreateThread(...);     **then I equal these to variable to each other**  h2=h1;

Comment: @biprinea I don't understand what you are trying to ask. You are just stating facts, not asking a real question. You *can* call `CreateThread()`, assign the `HANDLE` to one variable, and then assign that to another variable. But then what do yoylu want to do with those variables?